# Substract/Deduct 1 from a String VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a set of codes (C01.0001, S009.1002, A0056.0102), the only parameter to be true always is that there are the four numbers after the dot. My goal is to substract 1 (C01.0101-1= C01.0100, S009.0002-1=S009.0001,etc.). I've tried different ways to solve this but I'm stuck. Help please!!
Here's what I've got so far:

```
Sub Subsctruct_1()
    Dim myCode As String, myResult As String
'    Range("A1").Value = "C01.0002"

    myCode = Range("A1").Value
    myResult = Mid(myCode, Len(myCode) - 4, 5) - 1

    Debug.Print myResult '-0.9999
End Sub
```

This is the solution, thank's to Brian M Stafford's help:

```
Sub Get_Code()
    Dim Arr1 As Variant, ResNewCode As Variant
    Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long
    Dim EnvNm As String

    LastRow = ShStart.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Arr1 = ShStart.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Value
    ResNewCode = ShStart.Range("F2:F" & LastRow).Value

    For i = 1 To UBound(Arr1)
        If Arr1(i, 1) <> "" Then
            EnvNm = Subtract1(Arr1(i, 1))
            ResNewCode(i, 1) = EnvNm
        End If
    Next i

ShStart.Range("F2").Resize(UBound(ResNewCode, 1), 1).Value = ResNewCode
End Sub

Public Function Subtract1(ByVal Code As String) As String
'Brian M Stafford's Solution ===> Thanks!

   Dim v As Variant

   v = Split(Code, ".")
   Subtract1 = v(0) & "." & Format(Val(v(1)) - 1, "0000")
End Function
```

Comment: You say that the last four digits are always constant in size, but what about the character on the front?  Is this always present?  Either way, if it is there, is always a single character, or can its length vary (e.g. AB123.4567)?  Also, `S009.0002 - 1` is technically `S008.002`.  You need to be a bit more concise in what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another solution.  It always has four numbers after the dot:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command1_Click()
   MsgBox Subtract1("C01.0101")
   MsgBox Subtract1("S009.0002")
   MsgBox Subtract1("C01.0001")
   MsgBox Subtract1("C01.0100")
   MsgBox Subtract1("C01.0010")
End Sub

Private Function Subtract1(ByVal Code As String) As String
   Dim v As Variant

   v = Split(Code, ".")
   Subtract1 = v(0) & "." & Format(Val(v(1)) - 1, "0000")
End Function
```

Comment: Genius!! Thanks so much Brian! And everyone else that took time to suggest options.

Answer (score 1):

Might need more examples to fully understand what you need but this will work for your two examples

```
Sub x()

Dim s1 As String, s2 As String

s1 = "C01.0101"
s2 = "S009.0002"

s1 = Left(s1, Len(s1) - 1) & Val(Right(s1, 1)) - 1: MsgBox s1
s2 = Left(s2, Len(s2) - 1) & Val(Right(s2, 1)) - 1: MsgBox s2

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like so, called like `PopAndSubtract("00.0202.0002.0100",False)` giving a result of `99` or like `PopAndSubtract("00.0202.0002.0100")` to return `00.0202.0002.99`

```
Function PopAndSubtract(strInput As String, _
        Optional blnRebuildOuput As Boolean = True) As Variant

Dim a() As String
Dim l As Long
Dim i As Integer

a = Split(strInput, ".")

i = Len(a(UBound(a)))
l = CLng(a(UBound(a)))
l = l - 1
a(UBound(a)) = Format(l, String(i, "0"))


If Not blnRebuildOuput Then
    PopAndSubtract = l
Else
    PopAndSubtract = Join(a, ".")
End If

End Function
```

Comment: It almost works! But not quite. If I have a code like this "I.0010", and run your code, the result that gives is "I.001-1" but I need "I.0009"... It's a brainer... Thanks for your help Nathan!! Sending a sheet so you can checkout my codes.

Comment: @FerJen added a mod

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with a little more flexibility in case you need to subtract by more than 1, or you need a different number format e.g. there are suddenly 3 or 5 digits numbers.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Tests()
    'Given Cases
    Debug.Print SubtractFromString("C01.1001")
    Debug.Print SubtractFromString("S009.1002")
    Debug.Print SubtractFromString("A0056.0102")
    Debug.Print SubtractFromString("I.0010")

    'Other situations which might pop up, subtract by 2
    Debug.Print SubtractFromString("S009.1002", 2)

    'Subtract by 2, with 5 digits instead of 4
    Debug.Print SubtractFromString("S009.1002", 2, "00000")
End Sub

Public Function SubtractFromString(InputValue As String, _
                                   Optional SubtractAmount As Long = 1, _
                                   Optional NumberFormat As String = "0000") As String
    Dim StringArray As Variant: StringArray = Split(InputValue, ".")
    SubtractFromString = StringArray(0) & "." & _
                         Format(CLng(StringArray(1)) - SubtractAmount, NumberFormat)
End Function
```